# Sprint U300 4G/WiMax USB card - can it be made to work with OS X (Leopard)?

Tags: macos, usb, wimax

It seems that Sprint do not provide drivers for this USB adapter. Is there a way to make this work with Apple OS X, so that I can use it with my MacBook Pro? It appears to have USB storage and this is all that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://www6.sprint.com/downloads/sprint_smartview/executables/SSV_Mac2.28.0061.mpkg.zip

On Snow Leopard I had to install from terminal:

sudo installer -target Macintosh\ HD  -pkg ~/Downloads/Install\ Sprint\ SmartView.mpkg